# settings.bundle ios configure iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios8, nsbundle

I have a problema with iOS8 and the bundle settings, I have a textField where is insert a URL in the settings and use it in my app, but in iOS 8 do not save the text of textField, when I go out of setting and return the textField is in default.

Somebody may be know if in iOS 8 something change about bundle settings.

Another strange change about it, is in iOS8, it have something like this (image), but in iOS 7, the settings do not have IPHONE SETTINGS part.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: No I am waiting for the beta 4 because in apple forum a lot of people have the same problem.

Comment: I can confirm this still happens with the latest betas.  Hopefully the GM clears it up.

Comment: The GM has the same problem for me.

Comment: And this looks like the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134171/ios-setting-bundle-issue-with-ios-8-at-simulator

Comment: Las answer in apple forum.

Answer (score 1):

Last answer apple forum.

View or Reply online: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1038479#1038479

--- Fibonacci

I observed the same problem on the GM simulator, both with my app and the AppPrefs sample. When I installed the iOS 8 GM on a iPad 2 physical device, however, the problem went away.

So there is at least some hope that the bug is in the simulator only, and not in the system that will be landing on all our customers' devices in a week! If anyone else watching this thread can test on other physical devices with the GM system, please post your results here.

Comment: On physical devices with IOS 8 exist this part IPHONE SETTINGS. I don't think this is a bug at all.