# iOS setting.bundle issue with iOS 8 at simulator

Tags: ios8, settings.bundle, root.plist

when I use iOS 7 simulator ,

setting.bundle in my project can work effectively .
I change app settings by toggle switch and then immediately in to app setting again,the value changed as I just do.

but when go run iOS 8 simulator ,
every change in my custom-app-settings are not stored.

I have tried rebooting the device / reinstalling the app. It seems the switch has no effect only in iOS 8 simulator?

step:1
toggleswitch, change value and go back.
[image]

step:2
the same
[image]

Comment: Does it work correctly on a device with iOS 8?

Comment: I have the same issue with Xcode 6.0.1 (6A317) and iOS 8.0 (12A365) in iOS Simulator 8.0 (550.1). Works correctly on device though.

Comment: Same issue here: Xcode 6.0.1 (6A317) and IOS 8.0 (12A365) Simulator... Any news on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal now at Xcode 6 beta 7.＠＠

Comment: Good for you - it's broken for me on the Xcode 6 GM.

Comment: Xcode 6 GM, simulator doesn't keep settings for me :(

Comment: Same here. GM seems to have some issues.

Comment: Xcode 6 public release here, and it still doesn't save.

Comment: On Xcode 6.2 (6C131e) and real device iPhone 6 with iOS 8.2 still has the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

This has been fixed in Xcode 6.1 GM seed. simulator saves settings now :)

Answer (score 2):

I think is an XCode issue. Using XCode 6 beta6/ Beta7 / GM the Settings bundle work on iOS7 simulators but not 8.
The changes you make are supposed to be saved to the following path:

```
/Users/<User Name>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<iOS Version>
```

However the iOS versions there don't include 8.
I am waiting for the final XCode version.

Comment: I'm currently experiencing this issue with Xcode 6.0.1.

Comment: the path has changed for iOS 8 Simulators : `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{simulated device UUID}/data/Containers/Data/Application/{application UUID}/Library/Preferences/`. Use `xcrun simctl list` to find your simulator UUID. As to your App's UUID, search or add some code in your delegate like this : `NSLog(@"Documents Directory: %@", [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);`