# Xcode settings.bundle are not saved in setting pane on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, settings.bundle

I'm adding an settings.bundle file to my application on Xcode 6 and save it without any changes. When I run the application, I can see my application's settings in setting pane in simulator but when I change the value and go back to setting pane and re-enter to my app setting, changes are not shown and just default values are shown again. Am I do something wrong?

thanks alot

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing with Xcode 6 and this seems to be a [problem for others as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134171/ios-setting-bundle-issue-with-ios-8-at-simulator)